# MySQL select from a table by the result of a select from another table

Tags: mysql

1 db, 4 tables. I have to get inforomation from an item inside a table (table1 or table2 or table3); the name of the table where to search is inside a table named "codes". I have to query this table and then query the table i found...

*STRUCTURE:*

```
[ codes ]
id  |  table (table = name of table where the id is (in table1, table2 or table3)

[ table1 ]
id  |  info1 | info2 | info3

[ table2 ]
id  |  info1 | info2 | info3

[ table3 ]
id  |  info1 | info2 | info3
```

*MY QUERY:*

```
 $qry = "SELECT * FROM codes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
         $result = mysql_query($qry);

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $table = $row['table'];

            $qry2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = '$id'");
            $result2 = mysql_fetch_row($qry2);

            $model              = $result2[1];
            $brand              = $result2[2];

            echo $model . "," . $brand;
            }
```

This is a bad example of coding. I would like to do something like this "metacode": *select * where id (of the table) = id (of codes) select**ED** from codes ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5*.

Comment: So you want to do this in pure SQL, is that what you're asking? If so, search for *dynamic table name*, you'll find many answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll take a look.